# SQLAlchemy - aggregate inner query joining to outer query

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

The below is an example of a query which I'm trying to write in SQLAlchemy without much luck. I'm quite new to SQLA and am able to convert some queries but not this this:

```
select car, min(units)
from (
    select car,
    (select sum(case when side = 0 then 1 else -1 end * doors)
        from p.trades i
        where i.car = o.car and i.date = o.date
        and i.server_time <= o.server_time) units
    from p.trades o
    where date = '2016-01-19'
    and car in ('Golf')
    order by server_time, trade_id
) boff
group by car
```

Can anyone be of assistance?

Thanks, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is not what you expect, but I'd just use SQL query.
I worked with few different ORMs and my experience is that it is usually not worth trying to write relatively complex queries using object-like syntax.

Anything simple, like read / write a record or do a simple query, is usually obvious and clear, so it's easy to write it and to maintain it.
For more complex queries you will both spend time initially to convert to the ORM language and spend time later, when you need to modify it, to remember how it worked and to understand how it can be modified.

So I would just do this:

```
    data = session.query(MyModel).from_statement(text(
        """
        select * from 
          ....
          ....
        """)).params(x=a, y=b).all()
```